# Private Endpoint Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-private-link

We are currently creating snapshots from them creating VHD's to a storage account where we use the snapshots to create disks. I was wondering if there's a way to use private endpoint or private link to to keep the snapshots secure. I am working under the assumption the VHDs are sent to a storage account over the internet. We generate a SAS at the point of being copied. The requirement is to keep everything on the Azure network or to use private link\endpoint or service endpoint wherever possible.

Is this possible or does it need to go over the internet?

Thanks in advance and I hope ot makes sense.

Comment: I don't understand what this has to do with Azure DevOps.

Comment: @DanielMann I was hoping someone who works with DevOps might have come across this before, but I agree this could be any external service accessing azure blob, although would be good to know if devops uses the internet or azure backbone to connect to azure paas services :)

Comment: see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/disks-export-import-private-links-cli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your VMs are in Azure VNet, Yes you can transfer the disks through azure backbone network to a storage account using private endpoint configured. But if the Vms are on-premise private endpoints won't work and i am ot sure service endpoints work or not from on-premise

Comment: private endpoint does work from from on-premises. see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-adoption-framework/ready/azure-best-practices/private-link-and-dns-integration-at-scale